# run the python from specified directory

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to run python file by from different directory, but I want that directory to be current work directory.

For ex
Let's say below is my project structure

```
project_name/core/main.py
project_name/core/app1.py
project_name/core/app2.py
project_name/log/log.txt
project_name/config/userconfig/user.json
project_name/config/systemconfig/system.json
```

1. let's say Now I have opened `cmd` at project_name directory, where I can run `main.py`
   using this command `python core/main.py`

Now I if want to access `user.json` from I have to give path that `config/userconfig/user.json` in the code

2. I can also open `cmd` at core folder and I can run command that `python main.py`

Now I if want to access `user.json` from I have to give path that `../config/userconfig/user.json` in the code

So when I have to give path according to from where I'm running the code, how can I make my code always works regardless of from where I'm running my python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `__file__` variable to obtain the full pathname of `main.py`, get its directory path with `os.path.dirname`, and then join it with the relative path to the config file:

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'config', 'userconfig', 'user.json')
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try to use absolute paths. E.g. `C:/your/absolute/path/.../project_name/config/userconfig/user.json`

Comment: I can't try full path because I'll take it as exe and run it on client machine